# Which incarnations of Vishnu has different skin colors?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

[Here](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/8/13) is the verse of Bhagavata purana where Garga explains the colors of body of Vishnu in different incarnations.

> Your son Kṛṣṇa appears as an incarnation in every millennium. In the past, He assumed three different colors — white, red and yellow — and now He has appeared in a blackish color. SB.10.8.13

I understand that in Krishna-avatar He was blackish but I don't know which other avatars He was white, red and yellow.

Comment: Do you  want Shre Vishnu's  color in different  yugas , or in different avataras ie.incarnations?

Comment: Different Avatars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who are the red complexioned and yellow complexioned avataras mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32080/who-are-the-red-complexioned-and-yellow-complexioned-avataras-mentioned-in-srima)

Comment: Iskcon devotees say it was Chaitanya Mahaprabhu who was golden color

Answer (score 5):

[5th Chapter](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/5/) of 11th Canto of Srimad Bhagavatam describes white and red colors.

> SB 11.5.21 — In Satya-yuga **the Lord is white and four-armed, has
>   matted locks and wears a garment of tree bark. He carries a black
>   deerskin, a sacred thread, prayer beads and the rod and waterpot of a
>   brahmacārī.**
>
> SB 11.5.22 — People in Satya-yuga are peaceful, nonenvious, friendly
>   to every creature and steady in all situations. They worship the
>   Supreme Personality by austere meditation and by internal and external
>   sense control.
>
> SB 11.5.23 — In Satya-yuga the Lord is glorified by the names **Haṁsa,
>   Suparṇa, Vaikuṇṭha, Dharma, Yogeśvara, Amala, Īśvara, Puruṣa, Avyakta
>   and Paramātmā.**
>
> SB 11.5.24 — In Tretā-yuga **the Lord appears with a red complexion. He
>   has four arms, golden hair, and wears a triple belt representing
>   initiation into each of the three Vedas**. Embodying the knowledge of
>   worship by sacrificial performance, which is contained in the Ṛg, Sāma
>   and Yajur Vedas, His symbols are the ladle, spoon and other implements
>   of sacrifice.
>
> SB 11.5.25 — In Tretā-yuga, those members of human society who are
>   fixed in religiosity and are sincerely interested in achieving the
>   Absolute Truth worship Lord Hari, who contains within Himself all the
>   demigods. The Lord is worshiped by the rituals of sacrifice taught in
>   the three Vedas.
>
> SB 11.5.26 — In Tretā-yuga the Lord is glorified by the names **Viṣṇu,
>   Yajña, Pṛśnigarbha, Sarvadeva, Urukrama, Vṛṣākapi, Jayanta and
>   Urugāya.**

As far as I know, except mentioning that Lord's avatar is yellow in color here and some other places like in [Vishnu Saharsra nama.](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Vishnu_Sahasranamam) where 737th name is suvarnavarnah(He who is of golden color), there is no specific name associated with yellow colored incarnation.

Comment: It is still generic description. Does not say , which avatar was responsible for those colors

Comment: Golden colour is savitha sun Ray's  white color is vasudeva red is Naryayana or Narasimha

Answer (score 0):

God Rama was a Vishnu-avatara, born on Earth as the eldest son of King Dasharatha and Queen Kaushalya [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 1.15].

God Rama was dark-skinned [Ref: Valmiki Ramayana 2.88; Brahmanda Purana 2.3.63.193; Vayu Purana 2.26.191].

Source: 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani pgs 2-3