# Who are the red complexioned and yellow complexioned avataras mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, bhagavata-purana, gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya

Gargamuni, while naming Krishna, mentions that there are four types of complexions incarnations have:

> शुक्लरक्तस्तथा पीत इदानीं कृष्णतां गतः।
>
> The while coloured one could be the Hari who was related with the Gajendramoksha and incarnated in the Satya yuga, as He is referred to as शुक्लाम्वरधरं विष्णुं शशिवर्णं चतुर्भुजम्।

According to the Gaudiya Vaishnavas, Mahaprabhu Sri Chaitanya is the yellow-complexioned one, though the major Vaishnava sects dont accept this. Mahaprabhu of course could very well be the yellow-coloured complexioned. But then the red-coloured one becomes the incarnation of the Treta yuga. Who is He? And, who is this yellow-coloured incarnation according to other Vaishnava sects?

Comment: I think you already mentioned about gaudiya vaishnava view atleast on the yellow colored one, there is no need to tag gaudiya vaishnavism in it. Otherwise it appears that only gaudiya vaishnavs have to answer..

Comment: @RaRe let them let us know about the red one

Comment: @RaRe That was exactly i was asking to OP that does he want the answer from GV perspective , if yes then only  the TAG is needed , not in general.

Comment: duplicate of [which incarnations of vishnu has different colors](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15513/which-incarnations-of-vishnu-has-different-skin-colors)

Comment: If you just wanted the general answer then why you added Gaudiya Vaishnava details in your question.Such a thing lead to misinterpretation.Do avoid adding any irrelevant details in question.

Comment: Your question is "Who is He? And, who is this yellow-coloured incarnation according to other Vaishnava sects?" How many different answers you got from different Vaishnava sampradayas.? Do you think this answer's your question? Since you accepted it.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar yes because as the answer reads, there is no such detailed description of the yellow coloured incarnation at all in bhagabatam.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Parth, you should wait for others' answers.. Let others explain if they have any information from other puranas. You can unaccept it for the time being..and remove Gaudiya related tags. You will get other answers.

Comment: @RaRe its okay for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red colored lord is described in 5th chapter of 11th Canto of Srimad Bhagavatam.

> SB 11.5.24 — In Tretā-yuga the Lord appears with a red complexion. He
>   has four arms, golden hair, and wears a triple belt representing
>   initiation into each of the three Vedas. Embodying the knowledge of
>   worship by sacrificial performance, which is contained in the Ṛg, Sāma
>   and Yajur Vedas, His symbols are the ladle, spoon and other implements
>   of sacrifice.
>
> SB 11.5.25 — In Tretā-yuga, those members of human society who are
>   fixed in religiosity and are sincerely interested in achieving the
>   Absolute Truth worship Lord Hari, who contains within Himself all the
>   demigods. The Lord is worshiped by the rituals of sacrifice taught in
>   the three Vedas.
>
> SB 11.5.26 — In Tretā-yuga the Lord is glorified by the names **Viṣṇu,
>   Yajña, Pṛśnigarbha, Sarvadeva, Urukrama, Vṛṣākapi, Jayanta and
>   Urugāya.**

Comment: Any detailed description of the yellow coloured one?

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee you know how gaudiya vaishnavas explain it. There is no specific description like the above one about that in this chapter.