# Any references to Vishnu and his other avatars like Kalki and Vamana being black or dark-skinned?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, avatars, color

Most people are aware that [Krishna was a blackish-skinned person. Lord Rama is also depicted as blackish-skinned.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16767/21097)

[image]

But I have also heard that black is shri hari Vishnu's skin color, despite his blue aura. That's why he, Rama and Krishna all look exactly the same.

Kalki is also depicted looking just like Vishnu. And what about Vamana the dwarf? Are they also black people?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How will the Kalki avatar look like?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/how-will-the-kalki-avatar-look-like)

Comment: @Vivikta Thanks!! Only a fraction of it. I asked for Vishnu himself and various avatars (as many as possible). Please answer if you have info about them!

Comment: Vishnu himself? It's well established that for this Yuga he's *megha-varna* = the color of the Rain giving clouds. And all his avatars are said to possess more or less the same - *"megha-varna"* complexion scheme.

Comment: Yes I have clearly written Vishnu himself and also other avatars. @Vivikta

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which incarnations of Vishnu has different skin colors?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15513/which-incarnations-of-vishnu-has-different-skin-colors)

Comment: @YDS No I am asking specifically for BLACK