# Was Lord Rama greenish in skin color?

Tags: ramayana, rama, valmiki

Is there any scriptural reference which says that skin tone of  Lord Rama is green in color ? OR is Rama  somewhere depicted in green color ?

Comment: Why do you think he is green?

Comment: This might be useful: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32086/4732

Comment: You will find the the actual tone and skin color of Rama in below answer. - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7354/depiction-of-rama-and-krishna

Comment: Why do you want to know  whether Rama was greenish in color? Any specific reason?

Comment: At least in Bengal, Rama is depicted as Green and he has a moustache.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar art work